# SQLite Fts select query

Tags: android, database, sqlite, search, full-text-search

I am making a dictionary of over 20,000 words in it. So, to make it work faster when search data, i am using fts3 table to do it.
my select query:
`Cursor c=db.rawQuery("Select * from data where Word MATCH '"+word+"*'", null);`

Using this query, it will show all the word that contain 'word' , but what i want is to get only the word that contain the beginning of the searching word.
Mean that i want it work like this query:

```
Cursor c=db.rawQuery("Select * from data where Word like '"+word+"%'", null);
```

Ex: I have : apple, app, and, book, bad, cat, car.
when I type 'a': i want it to show only: apple, app, and

What can i solve with this?

Comment: how much implementation  did u  complete??

Comment: what is a db .schema ?

Comment: table(_id primary key not null autoincrement, word text)

Comment: i wonder if you need. fts then if you have just one simple text column

Comment: Because it has over 20,000 word, if i don't use fts, it will slow when i perform searching

Comment: if i use Select * from word where word like 's%', it seems slower

Comment: its because you have no index on column 'word'

Comment: also there are two search clauses: "like" and "glob". from no reason one is muuuuuch more faster then another, but i dont remember which one, you need to test it

Comment: Could you provide an example of your problem.  My android app uses an fts table, and match "abc*" returns only words starting with abc... Isn't that what you want? Android also uses a simple tokenizer so it only folds capitals to lowercase, it doesn't shorten words.

Answer (score 0):

FTS supports searching for the beginning of a string with `^`:

```
SELECT * FROM FtsTable WHERE Word MATCH '^word*'
```

However, the full-text search index is designed to find words inside larger texts.

If your `Word` column contains only a single word, your query is more efficient if you use `LIKE 'a%'` and rely on a normal index.
To allow an index to be used with LIKE, the table column must have TEXT [affinity](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#affinity), and the index must be declared as COLLATE NOCASE (because LIKE is not case sensitive):

```
CREATE TABLE data (
    ...
    Word TEXT,
    ...
);
CREATE INDEX data_Word_index ON data(Word COLLATE NOCASE);
```

If you were to use GLOB instead, the index would have to be case sensitive (the default).

You can use [EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN](http://www.sqlite.org/eqp.html) to check whether the query uses the index:

```
sqlite> EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN SELECT * FROM data WHERE Word LIKE 'a%';
0|0|0|SEARCH TABLE data USING INDEX data_Word_index (Word>? AND Word<?)
```

Comment: can u tell me about searching for the beginning of a string with ^, if  i use : Cursor c=db.rawQuery("Select * from data where Word MATCH '^"+word+"*'", null); is it correct?

Comment: @CL. seems you are an sql[ite] guru, do you know why glob is much faster than like, or the reverse, anyway one is much faster than another

Comment: can u explain me detail about your code here:
sqlite> EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN SELECT * FROM data WHERE Word LIKE 'a%';
0|0|0|SEARCH TABLE data USING INDEX data_Word_index (Word>? AND Word<?)

Comment: @user3106128 Run that query in any interactive tool (in this case, I've used the `sqlite3` command-line shell).

Answer (score 0):

```
table(_id primary key not null autoincrement, word text)
```

FTS table does not use the above attributes.  It ignores data type.  It does not auto increment columns other than the hidden rowid column.  "_id" will not act as a primary key here.  Please verify that you are implementing an FTS table

https://www.sqlite.org/fts3.html

> a datatype name may be optionally specified for each column. This is
>   **pure syntactic sugar**, the supplied typenames are not used by FTS or
>   the SQLite core for any purpose. The same applies to any constraints
>   specified along with an FTS column name - **they are parsed but not used
>   or recorded by the system in any way**.

As for your original question, match "abc*" already searches from the beginning of the word.  For instance match "man*" will not match "woman".